# Using get or insert functionality on one to many django models and modelforms

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-models, django-forms

**A] Summary:**

Using get or insert functionality on one to many django models, checking whether a record or relationship exists prior to adding a new one.

**B] Details:**

1] I have the following django model structure country (one) to City (many)

2] I am using ModelForm for displaying the form on the html page. The forms are passed as template values and the template values are then rendered on the html page

3] When the post request comes in, the code extracts the country and city form data , checks for validity and saves it.

**C] Issue/Item i need help with:**

1] I want to use the get_or_insert functionality with my country and city relationship

2] Basically, i want to check whether there is an existing country record in the database for the country selected by the user,

2.1] if the country exists, check if there is a city record for the selected country.

2.1.1] if the city record exists, we are good, no need to add another record

2.1.2] if the city record doesn't exist, create the city record and associate the country with it

2.2] if the country doesn't exist, create the country record, create the city record and associate the city record with the country record.

**C] Code Excerpts:**

*1] Models and forms --*

```
class UserReportedCountry(db.Model):
country_name = db.StringProperty( required=True,
                          choices=['Afghanistan','Aring land Islands']
                         )

class UserReportedCity(db.Model):
    country = db.ReferenceProperty(UserReportedCountry, collection_name='cities')
    city_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)   

class UserCountryForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = UserReportedCountry

class UserCityForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = UserReportedCity
        exclude = ('country', )
```

*2] code that prints the forms--*

user_country_form and user_city_form are passed from python code as template values

```
 __TEMPLATE_USER_COUNTRY_FORM = 'user_country_form'
 __TEMPLATE_USER_CITY_FORM = 'user_city_form'

 def get(self): 
   template_values = {
        self.__TEMPLATE_USER_COUNTRY_FORM: UserCountryForm(),
        self.__TEMPLATE_USER_CITY_FORM: UserCityForm()
    }

   #rendering the html page and passing the template_values
   self.response.out.write(template.render(self.__MAIN_HTML_PAGE, template_values))
```

*3] HTML code excerpt which displays the template values on the html page*

```
<div id="userDataForm">
<form method="POST" action="/UserReporting"> 
<table>
<!-- Printing the forms for users country, city -->
    {{ user_country_form }}
    {{ user_city_form }}     
 </table>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value= "submit">
 </form>
 </div>
```

*3] Code excerpt for saving the data --*

```
def post(self):
    self.store_user_data()
    self.redirect('/')

#method to save users data in the models UserReportedCountry, UserReportedCity
def store_user_data(self):
    #getting user's country and city
    user_reported_country =  UserCountryForm(self.request.POST)
    user_reported_city = UserCityForm(self.request.POST)

    if (user_reported_country.is_valid() and user_reported_city.is_valid()):
        #save the country data
        country_entity = user_reported_country.save()
        #save the city data, and relate county with city
        city_entity = user_reported_city.save(commit=False)
        city_entity.country = country_entity 
        city_entity.put()
        return
    else:
        return
```

Thankyou for reading.

[Edit#1]

@ Torsten, post gave me a pointer to get_or_insert, I then came across StackOverflow post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812832/get-or-create-matching-key-and-user-python-app-engine) and implemented the key_name functionality to user get_or_insert

Code for saving the record looks like follows:

```
def store_user_data(self):
    #getting user's country and city
    user_reported_country =  UserCountryForm(self.request.POST)
    user_reported_city = UserCityForm(self.request.POST)

    if (user_reported_country.is_valid() and user_reported_city.is_valid()):
        #save the country and city data
        country_record = self.store_country_data()
        city_record = self.store_city_data(country_record)
        return
    else:
        return

def store_country_data(self):
    user_reported_country_name = self.request.POST['country_name']
    key_name = self.sanitize_key_name(user_reported_country_name)
    country_entity = UserReportedCountry.get_or_insert(key_name, country_name = user_reported_country_name)
    country_entity.put()
    return country_entity

def store_city_data(self, country_record):
    user_reported_city_name = self.request.POST['city_name']
    key_name = self.sanitize_key_name("%s:%s" % (country_record.country_name, str(user_reported_city_name)) )
    city_entity = UserReportedCity.get_or_insert(key_name, 
                                                 city_name = user_reported_city_name, 
                                                 country= country_record)

    city_entity.put()
    return city_entity

def sanitize_key_name(self,key_name):
    return re.sub(r'\s', '', key_name.lower())
```

Request: Can someone please do a quick code review and let me know if i am doing something wrong or making some rookie mistakes?

Comment: All of the things you list as questions are statements. What is your question? What trouble are you having?

Comment: Sorry @Nick Johnson, for not being clear. Changed the section name to "Issue/Item i need help with", since the question was very detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_or_create` (the equivalent to your get_or_insert):

```
country, country_is_new = UserReportedCountry.objects.get_or_create(country_name=my_country_name)
city, city_is_new = UserReportedCity.objects.get_or_create(country=country, city_name=my_city_name)
```

Comment: @Torsten, thank you for your response. I searched the app engine API and found that get_or_create is not supported with google app engine.

Comment: @Torsten, your post gave me a pointer to get_or_insert functionality and i came across the key name post on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812832/get-or-create-matching-key-and-user-python-app-engine) and implemented the code pointed out in "EDIT#1" section of my original post. Can you please do a code review and let me know if i am making any mistakes ?

Comment: @lance_klusener, you didn't mention you want to use App Engine models and their query API instead of Django. I was assuming you talk about Django only. Though I should have seen this according to your models. :P

Comment: @lance_klusener, about the code review: get_or_insert returns more than one parameter (a tuple), so you should do something like " country_entity, is_new = UserReportedCountry.get_or_insert(key_name, country_name = user_reported_country_name)" (similiar to get_or_create in Django). After get_or_insert you don't need a "country_entity.put()" anymore. Except this it moght work. I didn't try your code myself though. More information about get_or_insert in app engine here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert

Comment: @Torsten, thank you for your quick response and thank you for your code review. I didn't realize that the additional put is not needed . I have removed "city_entity.put()" and "country_entity.put()
" from the code. In the code excerpt you provided "country_entity, is_new = UserReportedCountry.get_or_insert(key_name, country_name = user_reported_country_name)", I dont understand why do i need the parameter "is_new" and what do i do with it ?

Comment: According to the get_or_insert documentation "The method returns an instance of the model class that represents the requested entity, whether it existed or was created by the method.". So that means it returns two parameters (actually it return one parameter which is a python tuple I guess: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: If you don"t add this extra variable "country_entity" will be simply a tuple including the model object as the first (country_entity[0]) and the if it was created or already existed as second argument (a boolean value, country_entity[1]). If you do it like I suggested it will put the first parameter into the country_entity variable and the second_parameter in the is_new variable. In any case, you should try out if everything works and also check things more carefully. As said, I didn't try the code myself.

Comment: Thanks @Torsten for your response. I tried the code mentioned in "Edit#1" section of the main posting and it is working as designed. In the current design, i am not interested in the boolean value "is_new" which indicates whether the entity was created or it existed.